# React Js if-else build up

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to Reactjs. I'm currently learning how to build an if else statement but can't seem to properly do it.

```
{voucherDetails.target_shop_name_validation ? (

          if ( A > 5 ) {
          setDisabled(true);}  // not sure how to properly build if here
          

          ) :

          <Button

            title="SEE NEARBY SHOP"
            buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
            titleStyle={{fontSize:13}} 
            disabled={isDisabled}   
            onPress={NearByShop}                     
          />
        
          }
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a validation need to pass in "A". For short, if A is more than 5 , I would like to disable the button "SEE NEARBY SHOP". However, I do not know how to properly build the first section of the validation

Comment: It's still a little unclear without looking at additional code. You should separate the return values of the conditions since one of them is setting state and the other is returning an element

Comment: You can have multiple returns in a component. Just set your invalid breakout condition at the top and handle it there. If it doesn't fail, it will just continue on. For example: `if (isBad) return <><button title='fail' /></>`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I you would try this for an if else

```
{x ? y : a}
```

But in your case I see an outer if statement and an if and else inside of it, so I dont think this would work. However the following should.

```
{(() => {
    if (voucherDetails.target_shop_name_validation){
        if ( A > 5 ) {
            setDisabled(true);
        }  // not sure how to properly build if here
        else {
            return (
                <Button

                title="SEE NEARBY SHOP"
                buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
                titleStyle={{fontSize:13}} 
                disabled={isDisabled}   
                onPress={NearByShop}                     
                />
            )
    }
})()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be doing something like this:

```js
{voucherDetails.target_shop_name_validation
  ? (
    (A > 5) && setDisabled(true)
  ) : (
    <Button
      title = "SEE NEARBY SHOP"
      buttonStyle={{
        backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
        borderRadius: 10
      }}
      titleStyle={{ fontSize: 13 }}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      onPress={NearByShop}
    />
  )
}
```

However this logic seems a bit weird since you are setting disabled to true in the if statement, and in the else statement you use the value of isDisabled, which would never render the value true you set above.

Maybe a better approach would be to check for `(A > 5)` and then `setDisabled(true)` before you render your component, and then you can change your code to:

```js
{!voucherDetails.target_shop_name_validation &&
  (
    <Button
      title = "SEE NEARBY SHOP"
      buttonStyle={{
        backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
        borderRadius: 10
      }}
      titleStyle={{ fontSize: 13 }}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      onPress={NearByShop}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How if we use `useEffect` to watch the `A` value, and when the `A` value greater than 5 then the `isDisabled` state will be set to `true`;

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [A, setA] = useState(0);
  ...

  // setA somewhere in your code

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsDisabled(A > 5);
  },[A]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
    {!voucherDetails.target_shop_name_validation && (
      <Button
        title="SEE NEARBY SHOP"
        buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
        titleStyle={{fontSize:13}} 
        disabled={isDisabled}   
        onPress={NearByShop}                     
      />
    )}
    ...
  )
}
```